# Extract the gesture from GestureRecognizerResult

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediapipe

In the `mediapipe` library, there is a task called `GestureRecognizer` which can recognize certain hand gestures. There is also a task called `GestureRecognizerResult` which consists of the results from the `GestureRecognizer`. `GestureRecognizerResult` has an attribute called `gesture`, which when printed shows the following output

```
> print(getattr(GestureRecognizerResult, 'gestures'))
#[[Category(index=-1, score=0.8142859935760498, display_name='', category_name='Open_Palm')]]
```

I actually want just the `category_name` to be printed, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `category_name = getattr(GestureRecognizerResult, 'gestures').split("category_name='")[-1].rsplit("')")[0]` - split at `category_name='`, take the latter part, split again at `')` and take the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mp/tasks/vision/GestureRecognizerResult), `GestureRecognizerResult` has the following attributes:

```py
mp.tasks.vision.GestureRecognizerResult(
    gestures: List[List[category_module.Category]],
    handedness: List[List[category_module.Category]],
    hand_landmarks: List[List[landmark_module.NormalizedLandmark]],
    hand_world_landmarks: List[List[landmark_module.Landmark]]
)
```

The `gestures` attribute is a List of gestures, each with a List of categories, so you can access those categories using the following:

```py
for gesture in recognition_result.gestures:
    print([category.category_name for category in gesture])
```